# Loading a local glTF file into Javascript memory

Tags: javascript, three.js, capacitor, gltf

I am using three.js and Capacitor to create a native iOS and Android app. I have some GLTF models that I want to load from some sort of asset folder that is bundled up with the code and delivered to a user, but I am not sure how to go about this.

[This](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader.load) documentation on the GLTF Loader's `load` function, requires some sort of url. [Parse](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader.parse), however, takes in a "glTF asset to parse, as an ArrayBuffer". How can I load this glTF file into memory and what is the best practice for doing so? I tried `import * as Model from './models/myModel.gltf'` but got a `Cannot find module` error.

Answer (score 1):

Here my method to load a gltf file, I'm using `reader` to load any file in my scene, then it's parsing with `loader.parse`.
But if you want sample models folder I think you don't need reader method and parser. Just using load GLTF basic method and store your samples in an array or object.
I hope I helped you.

```
loadGltf(file, filename) {
        reader.onload = readerEvent => {
            const contents = readerEvent.target.result;
            const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader()
            try {
                loader.parse(contents, '', function (gltf) {
                    gltf.scene.traverse(function(child) {
                        if (child.isMesh) {
                            child.castShadow = true;
                            child.receiveShadow = true;
                        }
                    });
                    currentModel = gltf.scene;
                    scene.add(gltf.scene);
                });
            }
            catch(error) {
                alert("Your file " + Load.filename + " was not parsed correctly." + "\n\n" + "ERROR MESSAGE : " + error.message);
            }
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
```